# error: could not find or load main class <class Name>

Tags: java, program-entry-point

```
package demo;
import java.io.*;
class A
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("This Is Class A : public void run()");
    }
}
class B
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Main Method Executed");
        A obj1 = new A();
        obj1.run();
    }
}
```

Compile :

```
d:\java>javac -d . demo.java
```

---> class file be created in directory demo [ A.class, B.class]

```
Run : d:\java>java B
Error: could not find or load main class B
```

but if I remove the line 1 [package demo;] than it run proper.
so, when we use package name than why "Error: could not find or load main class B" error be generated.

Comment: Try to start with : `java demo.A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command. Because main method is in **B class**. The name of the package is `demo` and class containing main method is `B`.

```
java demo.B
```

---

**Output :**
Main Method Executed
This Is Class A : public void run()

> but if I remove the line 1 [package demo;] than it run proper.

This because when you provide the package declaration in your program, then your classes reside in the package. So you need to provide the complete path to access them from your package.

Comment: thanks, I done it. but if I go on package directory like

Comment: but if I go on package directory like > cd demo [set current directory 'd:\java\demo>'] than I try >java B, than also give "error could not find or load main class B" while B.class reside in demo[package] directory.

Comment: @KumarHarsha I never said to inside the directory. Just run the command after compiling your code. Original which you have posted here.

Comment: @KumarHarsha the answer you have accepted have asked you change you couple of things. don't change anything into your original code. compile with the command you have pasted and then run with my command from the answer.

Comment: yes your answer is correct ... that way I done this. but I face some problem when I go on package directory than try to run >java B. but it has same error, please help. how it working.

Comment: @KumarHarsha I have already mentioned in the answer. Your class is defined as demo.B, so the when you any java B, even from demo directory, it will not work. It will not find that class. So you run the program from base directory, by specifying the package name, java command will automatically search for the directory and run the class.

Answer (score 2):

it should be as below since you have declared a package structure and the class file should reside in such a folder structure. As in your A.class should be in demo folder

```
>java demo/A
```

Also it seems you have main method in class B. So you'll have to execute class **B instead of A**

```
>java demo/B
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your demo.java as B.java and use

```
public class B
```

instead of

```
class B
```

Suppose B.class is located at C:\

To compile B.java, type

```
C:\javac -d . B.java
```

This would create a folder named "demo" which contains 2 class files named A.class and B.class.

To execute the program, type

```
C:\demo\java demo.B
```

Here's the result of the program:

```
Main Method Executed
This Is Class A : public void run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your **Main** class resides in the **controller** package. if you're using Gradle for building and testing your application, then make sure you've these lines in your **build.gradle** file:

```
jar {
    manifest {
      def classpath = configurations.runtime.collect { jarfile ->
        '../lib/' + jarfile.getName()
      }.join(' ')

       attributes 'Main-Class': 'controller.Main', 'Class-Path': classpath, 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

task runit(type: JavaExec) {
    main 'controller.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Note: **controller** is the name of my package. My **Main** class is inside the **controller** package, and it works well, even executing as a standalone application. Remember to change the name of the package of where your Main class resides.